# Dibujar? se podria decir. (java)

Tags: java

Sucede que se nos dio la tarea de crear un Main que pueda imprimir la siguiente figura con el uso de "for":

```
 @
 @@@
@@@@@  en el caso n=3.
 @@@
  @



 @
  @@@
 @@@@@
@@@@@@@ en el caso de n=4.
 @@@@@
  @@@
   @
```

y así de manera sucesiva... 
  se nos dio el siguiente metodo que cumple con la "mitad" es decir:

```
@
  @@@
 @@@@@
@@@@@@@ en el caso de n=4.

for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
 for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
  System.out.print(" ");
  }
 for(int j=1;j<=n*2;j++){
  System.out.print("@ ");
 }
}
}
```

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Kurosou, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Deberías enseñar lo que has intentado puesto que solo has puesto el enunciado de un ejercicio y aquí no se resuelven tareas del colegio. Pon lo que has intentado y donde has fallado para que te podamos ayudar. Puedes leer [ask] para rehacer tu pregunta. Ánimo que no es difícil lo que quieres hacer.